# Mongoose - How to select all by specific field and return data as array of strings

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the collection of documents in the following format:

```
"_id": "12345",
"userId" : "some user id",
"regId" : "some reg id"
```

Im trying to select all documents by regId field and return an array of regIds.

**Desired result:**

```
["some reg id","some reg id","some reg id","some reg id" ....]
```

What i tried is :

```
Device.find({}, { "regId": 1, _id: 0 },  function(err, doc){
    if(!err){
        console.log("Documents" , doc);
    }
});
```

What i get is : 
[image]

I know that I can iterate the result and push the regId values into new Array object, but that would be a heavy task. Because I'm expecting to have around 10K-50K documents. Any ideas?

Comment: So why would you want an array with 50K entries anyway? What would be the advantage?

Comment: I think that the performance hit of retrieving 10K-50K documents from the database will (far) outweigh plucking the `regId` property from each of those documents.

Comment: @BlakesSeven those regId are Android device tokes. I need to send an array of tokens to Ionic servers to send push notifications.

Comment: I'm thinking that "even if" you used a cursor to process then you are still "stuffing an array" in your application with 50K entries. This cannot be what you really want. What do you really want to do? There has to be better way.

Comment: @BlakesSeven According to ionic documentations, I need to send an array of tokens. http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push  . Procassing such amount of documents in Mongoose should be ok. Im just having trouble with my query. Can i modify it to get the desired result?

Comment: @VanderVidi how often do you need to do this (send a push notification)?

Comment: Let me give you a chance to redeam yourself here ( before I even consider reading documentation for something I do not want to do myself right now ) do you really think that an external API is going to to be happy with a list contructed of 50K items, or that your application is going to be happy ( or are you even aware that mongoose is already creating an in memory array already, unless you tell it otherwise ). I would go back and look at the documentation again and think about which metohds allow "batch" submission in some way, and how you open and close a batch of operations like that.

Comment: @robertklep Not very often. sometimes every few minutes and sometimes once in a few days.

Comment: Quick glance. So it's XML and you could always stream from a cursor stream etc etc ( big broad topic ). But I would put money on it that if you tried to do such a submission it would break and complain wildly. It seems you should be breaking this into "batches" yourself. Hence basically look at "cursors" and "streams".

Comment: @BlakesSeven to be fair, the Ionic docs don't specify any limits. No idea where you're getting _"it's XML"_ from though, the API accepts JSON.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I provided the link to the documentation just to show you the structure of the json the API expects. It is the same as using Google Cloud Messaging. They both expect an array of tokens. Ofcourse stuffing an array in the application it self is wrong. I agree with you. Mongoose does it faster. I can also use Underscore but im trying to avoid stuffing an array myself.

Comment: @BlakesSeven The API accepts JSON with a tokens array.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Its sent as a JSON! meaning a text file. How the API server process the data is not my problem. Can you refer to my question?

Comment: I am referring to your question and I am asking you to think about what you are asking. You do not really want to send 50K requests all at once, and nor do you want to load that content from your database into memory just to do so. I already told you to look at "cursor" and "stream" processing with mongoose ( very easy search ) and you need to break up your push request messages into managable batches. Save yourself the pain  as if you try it is almost certain to break the receiving API. Not to mention the hurt you are doing to your application.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want duplicates, you can directly get an array of the unique `regId` values in the collection using [`distinct`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.distinct):

```js
Device.distinct('regId', function(err, regIdsArray) {...});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i will give it a try in the following days

Comment: Helpful for me.